# Transit via Kuwait

Tags: transit, kuwait

I am travelling from Frankfurt to India..  First i will take the one airlines from Frankfurt to Kuwait, and later transit from Kuwait to india via Indigo. Is a visa required to transit in Kuwait, as i have a self transfer option?

Comment: Add your details here and see what you get. You need to provide WAY more detail than what's in the question . https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm